# AngularJS: controller not connected to view when dynamically routed

Tags: angularjs

So, I guess this question is more academic than anything. I've been working all afternoon on a MEAN stack application's reset password functionality, and the general method I chose to employ is as follows:

1. In the login view, the user enters their username and clicks the forgot password button.
2. This submits a post request to the server's /forgot route, along with the { username: username } object.
3. The server looks for the user in the database, and if found, it creates a long string of random characters (e.g. `'823uhr8824hriij3993'`) and saves the string as the user's remember token (valid for an hour, and the expiration is also saved).
4. An email is sent out to the user with a link to reset the password, corresponding to Angular route `'/reset/:token'` (continuing the example,  `'/reset/823uhr8824hriij3993'`).
5. If the user submits an updated password from that url before the token expires, the server checks the params for the appropriate remember token and their password is successfully changed.

I am using ng-Route, and my reset password route is configured as:

```
.when('/reset/:token', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/account/reset-password.html',
  controller: 'resetPasswordCtrl'
})
```

Unless I am missing something blatant (which is entirely possible), when the user hits the `'/reset/823uhr8824hriij3993'` route and Angular renders the `reset-password.html` view, it should be connected to the `resetPasswordCtrl`, should it not?

I spent a couple hours today trying to troubleshoot the username, password, and password confirmation validations that were not working, many of which are coded in the `resetPasswordCtrl`, figuring there must have been some typo somewhere causing a disconnect. But in fact the controller wasn't actually connected to the view until I put `ng-controller="resetPasswordCtrl"` in the topmost div tag.

All the other routes in this application are static and are set up via the $routeProvider just as above, and this is the first time I've run into this issue, so I suppose it must arise because of the dynamic `/:token` portion of the route. Anyway, my immediate problem is solved, but if someone wouldn't mind taking a moment to explain why it was a problem in the first place, I would really appreciate it... for future reference!

Comment: Yes it should be bound to controller by $routeProvider and adding `ng-controller` should actually create 2 instances

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But in this case it only works with the ng-controller tag. Took me entirely too long to figure that out.

Comment: never seen that happen before and router should actually reject the path if it can't resolve controller. None of this sounds right...something is wrong somewhere

Answer (score 0):

as I can see the problem is your reset password page come directly from server so the angular itself and routing you wrote do not work there because all the works handle by a server itself so if you want to use that functionality you should create a separate html file like('reset.html') with all tags and everything you need to load your app and controller then point it to servers response page
In that case when server going to serve reset page it's came up with actual page

Comment: I might not have explained the setup thoroughly enough, but the only thing that comes from the server in the current setup is the generated remember token. The template is on the client side, and the client-side route loads and renders the template regardless of what string you substitute for `:token`. But when the user submits the reset password from the dynamic route via post request to the server, the server grabs the req.params.token and checks that it matches the user's remember token, and that it's not expired, before saving the new password. (Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer...)

Comment: in number 4 in your question you wrote {An email is sent out to the user with a link to reset the password },  am I right? then Your server link to reset password page and because of that your angular not doing any route in there so it is the server who serve page instead of your client angular. hope this will help